# Insert html paragraphs - jquery does more than expected

Tags: jquery, html

I pull some text out of MySQL and process it before shipping it back to jquery via an Ajax call.

One part of the processing in perl is to replace all newlines with paragraph tags. So I thought a simple:

```
s#\n#</p><p>#g;
```

.... then wrap the whole string in:

```
<p> ... </p>
```

... should do the trick. It worked, but I spotted a typo - I had omitted the closing para tag from the regex - so it read:

```
s#\n#<p>#g;
```

...and yet each paragraph was still wrapped correctly in P tags when it got to the browser.  So whether I have the closing P tag in the regex or not, jQuery does the right thing.

My question is why??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not actually jQuery doing this, it's the browser.

When you insert into the DOM, the browser will attempt to make sense of your tags and close any loose ends. Some browsers do this better than others.

Comment: Yes, of course, you're absolutely right. So it wasn't voodoo after all. Thanks a lot for clearing that up for me.